# Multi line text field with enhanced rich text is displaying text with an awkward format and extra empty lines are created in the email notification

Tags: designer-workflow, rich-text, formatting, sharepoint-email, multiline-text-field

Please help me in how to correct the format of the text display in the email body.
I saw an answer from Ms. Erin L but, I couldn't understand exactly what I should do.
Instead of changing the data type of the sharepoint column, I saw the suggestion as change the ***Return Field*** to *plain text* in the workflow. please explain me how to do that in the workflow. any solution to the issue is highly appreciated!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the SharePoint multiline column setting, and change the return type to **plain text** instead of reach text.  Then try again.

And also you could use **string builder** action in the SharePoint designer workflow to make good looking.

Sample Example on how description field was customized using the string builder here :

[Nicely formatted Workflow Task Descriptions](https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/nicely-formatted-workflow-task-descriptions/)

Comment: first of all, thank you for the response!

Comment: but, the return type in workflow is already set to plain text. and I do not want to change the list column type from enhanced rich text(which is current type) to plain or to rich text. Your response string builder action in the workflow - I have not done or do no know as of now. I have to dig the info on the string builder action. if there is any information on the String Builder action, can you please mention? thank you very much again!

Comment: I found the String Builder window for retrieving the data for Workflow Context like "current item URL, current site URL, etc., but, I am not sure how to get that String Builder window for retrieving data from the SharePoint List column. any help is highly appreciated in returning the text in the proper format in the auto-email!